# Find a 1x3 matrix with resultant as zero matrix

Tags: matlab, null, matrix-multiplication

I know a 3x3 matrix M, and I want to find a 1x3 matrix P. The given condition is:

```
[p1 p2 p3]*[m11 m12 m13; m21 m22 m23; m31 m32 m33] = [0 0 0]
```

Given is `[m11 m12 m13; m21 m22 m23; m31 m32 m33]`

I have to find non trivial (non-zero) solution of `[p1 p2 p3]` using Matlab.

I am wanting to be done in Matlab because its part of a code. If needed, given also is a condition:
 `p1 + p2 + p3 = 1`

**P.S:** I have tried the 'inv' function which gives the inverse of a matrix, however it is giving trivial solution. I have also read about the `'svg'` and `'null'` functions, but I doubt that they are meant for the `Ax=B` type, where as my problem is `xA=B` type.

Comment: to solve xA = 0, just transpose A first giving T and then solve Tx = 0
Also, if A is invertible, then the kernel only contains the trivial solution.

Comment: A is not invertible.

I tried this as you suggested, however I don't understand this step

P = null(-6*eye(3)-B)

 
I can't make an Identity matrix with my E matrix. 

Also at the end the result is 3x2 matrix, however for my result it should be 1x3.

Comment: if the result of null() is a 3x2 matrix that means that the kernel is 2 dimensional. If you just want one 1x3 vector, just take any linear combination of the two columns of the 3x2 matrix and transpose it.

Comment: Thanks Chris so far.

However please take a look at this P = null(-6*eye(3)-B). The '6' here is common element in the matrix 'D' derived, however in my matrix 'D' there are no common elements. What to keep in place of '6' if I dont have any common element?

Comment: sorry, you've lost me. What are the definitions of B, eye(3), D and E?
I'm guessing eye(3) might be the 3x3 identity matrix?

Comment: [V,D] = eig(A) produces matrices of eigenvalues (D) and eigenvectors (V) of matrix A, so that A*V = V*D. Matrix D is the canonical form  of A — a diagonal matrix with A's eigenvalues on the main diagonal. Matrix V is the modal matrix — its columns are the eigenvectors of A.

B is my matrix M above in the question.

Comment: ok, I guess that in the case above all the eigenvalues are the same value (-6) so it can be pulled out as a common factor. In your case the eigenvalues are different, so you can't pull out a common factor, but that doesn't make any fundemental difference to the calculation.

Comment: So how to do calculation in my case then? Since there's only single element multiplied with the identity matrix, I'm not sure how to go ahead with my type of matrix with different eigenvalues.

Comment: ok, I understand now. The problem is to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of a 3x3 matrix. If v is an eigenvalue, then Ax = vx for some vector x, so (A - Iv)x = 0. For this to have a non-trivial solution det(A - Iv) = 0, which gives a cubic polynomial in v (the characteristic polynomial). Solving this gives 3 values for v: v1, v2, v3 say. Then to find the corresponding eigenvectors solve (A - Ivi)x = 0 for each vi. This last step can be done using the null() function.

Comment: Thanks Chris. However the step I asked you is the one where you left to me saying "This last step can be done using the null() function." Before this I understood the concept of how to find eigenvalues and hence eigen vectors. My eigenvalues are not common (similar), and thus in using null I will have more than one number which could be used. Which eigen value do I choose to be used in 'null'when multiplying with identity (eye) matrix?

Comment: solve (A - Ivi)x = 0 for each vi
i.e. call null() three times, once for each eigenvalue

Comment: Ok. I will try that and let you know if I get the correct answer. Thanks for keeping up.

Comment: Chris: My eigen values are: -22.0711, 0, -7.9289. For both, the first and third eigenvalues, I get empty matrix (3-by-0) on calling null. While for eigenvalue of 0 I get eigen vector as [-0.5774;-0.5774;-0.5774]. However this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Matlab have a function for calculating the kernel of a matrix? If so, you should be able to use that.

Looks like it does: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/45457

Answer (score 0):

This problem Ax=b can be solved using the gaussian algorithm.